# TRIM High level or low level? and Running a VM on a ssd

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ssd, trim

Is TRIM high level (such as deleting files within the operating system) or low level (it monitors all disk activity). For instance if I run a VM within my windows 7 host, will the data deleted and written on the VM be affected by trim? Or does it bypass it?

In other words is running a VM on a ssd bad for the ssd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRIM is high-level, to use your terminology. The host OS just sees one large virtual disk file which does not get deleted, so TRIM won't really come into play at all, regardless of what you do on the guest OS.

That said, SSDs have actually grown to be pretty hardy as of late. You'll be replacing it before you wear out the NAND chips most likely.

Comment: Does trim come into play with pagefiling?

Comment: I don't think so. The page file is just one big file on your disk, which doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The VM doesn't actually access directly to the disk, it's managed by the host OS. So it's disk usage won't bypass anything.

But technically, a VM does not make much more disk acces than a real machine. However, the bottleneck when using your VM will probably not be on disk acces, but in graphics or processor speed.

So, if you're doing it only for speed, I don't think you'll gain a lot by running it on your SSD.